# Set margin between two tabel-cell div

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I have two buttons, and because I need them display in one line and vertical align text in it, I use `display: table-cell`. But the two div stick together. Margin does not work here. Is there a way to separate them?

Code is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sy8VC/

Comment: Vertical align only work in `table-cell`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you care if there is an extra `<div>` in between? If not, this could work:

```
<div id="select">
    <div class="btparent" id="parent1">parent1</div>
    <div style="width: 3px;display:table-cell;"></div>
    <div class="btparent" id="parent2">parent2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! I have tried `<div style="margin: 10px;display:table-cell;"></div>`, but haven't thought of using `width`.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use

`#select .btparent { display:inline-block; }`

?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use `float` in your css instead of `display: table-cell`.
Here is after I tweak your code. And if you use `float`, don't forget to add any **clear floating** methods in the container (#select)

```
#select {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  /* one of clear floating method: use 'overflow:hidden' */
  overflow: hidden;
}
  #select .btparent {
    border: 5px #AEE239 solid;
    color: #2D332D;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-family: Palatino;
    font-size: 16px;
    background: #D9E6BB;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100px;
    /* change here */
    height: 20px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
    /* ----------- */
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
  }
```

Hope this helps you..